# Why save and duplicate completely messes up the product URL?

Tags: magento2, product, admin

I usually use the save & duplicate option and I've noticed that whenever I do that it always uses the URL from the first product I created and then I will create other products by changing the product name and maybe another option and every URL will be the exact same with a different number at the end and I don't know how to fix this or if this is a known issue with Magento 2.1.6

**Example:**

I started by creating this product:

https://www.ooples.com/black-butler-ciel-pink-ballgown-5-plush-keychain.html

Here are the next 2 products I created using save & duplicate:

https://www.ooples.com/black-butler-ciel-pink-ballgown-5-plush-keychain-1.html
https://www.ooples.com/catalog/product/view/id/54914/s/black-butler-ciel-pink-ballgown-5-plush-keychain-2/

Not only are both URLs completely wrong but even the format for the second one is completely different from the others and all of my URLs are set to be like the first one. I don't change any settings other than product name and the product photo and maybe a category here or there.

Comment: This issue is still occurring in 2.4.2-p1 and would love to see an answer or if this is being fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Very belated response: Product duplication does a few things duplicated stupidly

1. sku created automatically from previous sku
2. stocks duplicated and created for that (likely to be temporary) sku and they remain in the stock tables if the sku is changed when the product is saved (that's a bug)
3. seo url created from previous one stupidly
4. certain actions like the rewrites, which are triggered on a normal change/save are not triggered by copy creation, and when you save since you don't change anything they aren't triggered either (sql imports can have the same issue)

**to return to your particular point here, url-key and rewrites / seo**

The url key is hidden in the Search Engine Optimization section and you can correct it there. If you change it and save, your URLs will be regenerated correctly.

If by some miracle the url-key generated is one you liked, you need to change it and save then change it back, in order for these "on change" actions to be triggered. Otherwise you stay with these stupid URLs.

I hope this helps